# Get Variation ID and Attribute Value on Product page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, product, cart

I wish to have a Quick Buy (Flipkart like) button on product page. Clicking on this button adds the selected product to cart and gets the user to the checkout (not on the cart page). Also note here that the user is not redirected to the cart page and takes the user in the checkout process as far as possible. I also do not want to replace default “add to cart” button, instead, I want to add another button that says Quickbuy. Can you help me with this?

What I have figured out so far?
Well, I have tried and create a URL structure that add products to cart and goes to checkout, something like this.

https://www.similarfeathers.com/checkout/?add-to-cart=6711&variation_id=6714&attribute_pa_size=M

[image: Custom Attribute from the Drop Down]

(6711 being the product ID, 6714 being that variable ID, M being that size (attribute)).
Now, I want to add this hyperlink, that gets generated dynamically on the product page, takes the value of size attribute from the dropdown and get variationID. When a user will click this URL, my job will be done.

Any way to create the custom hyperlink URL on the product page?

Comment: Since it's dynamically changing, you're going to have to use JavaScript. Are the product_id, variable_id, and attribute all shown in the html code? If so, you should be able to pull those attributes, and modify the `href` of the new button when the size changes.

Comment: No they are not shown on the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the required data to craft the link you are looking for is available on the single page in the form of hidden fields.

`<input type="hidden" value="6438" name="add-to-cart">
<input type="hidden" value="6438" name="product_id">
<input type="hidden" value="6442" name="variation_id">`

The value for `attribute_pa_size` can be grabbed from the select box.

You need to add the quick buy button, and on its click event write some code to craft the URL and redirect to it.

Some quickly made up code presuming that you create the button with `id="quick-buy"`

```
<script>
jQuery( document ).ready( function() {

    jQuery( "#quick-buy" ).click( function() {

        // Get all the values needed for the URL
        var add_to_cart = jQuery( 'input[name="add-to-cart"]' ).val();
        var variation_id = jQuery( 'input[name="variation_id"]' ).val();    
        var pa_size = jQuery( "#pa_size" ).val();

        // Craft the URL
        var link = "https://www.similarfeathers.com/checkout/?add-to-cart=" + add_to_cart + "&variation_id=" + variation_id + "&attribute_pa_size=" + pa_size

        // Finally redirect to the URL
        window.location.href= link;

        return false;

    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for all the help and effort.
Although the page redirects to the same page after I click the button, but adds the item in the cart. Can you suggest what to do?

Comment: Hi, as mentioned, I quickly cooked up the code so you may need to polish it. Have updated my code try that and see if it works.

Comment: Still the same issue. It redirects to the same page again.

Comment: There are a lot of other JS errors on your site, consider fixing them first.

Comment: Hi tried commenting you line `window.location.href = link;` and it still works the same, i.e. , redirects to the same page. That means this code is not working. I am not a jQuery person, could you please point out the error?

Comment: I cannot use a button here, any button I use is executing the same code as that of the Add To Cart button.

Comment: I have updated the code above and tested locally to confirm that its working. Don't comment the `window.location.href` code that is what actually does the redirection.

Comment: I cannot use a button in this page because it is a partial template. Any button I create executes nothing but the ADD TO CART code written somewhere. If I use a DIV instead, it does nothing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64483/discussion-between-anand-and-samarth-agarwal).

Answer (score 2):

global $product;

```
    $args = array(
                 'post_type'     => 'product_variation',
                 'post_status'   => array( 'private', 'publish' ),
                 'numberposts'   => -1,
                 'orderby'       => 'menu_order',
                 'order'         => 'asc',
                 'post_parent'   => $product->id
             );
             $variations = get_posts( $args ); 

    foreach ( $variations as $variation ) {


                echo  $variation_id           = absint( $variation->ID );$variable_id = $this['variation_id'];
                 $variation_post_status  = esc_attr( $variation->post_status );

                 $variation_data         = get_post_meta( $variation_id );
                 $variation_data['variation_post_id'] = $variation_id;

             echo get_post_meta( $variation_data['variation_post_id'], 'variable_regular_price[]', true) . '<br>';



                echo $id = $product->id.'<br>';
                 echo $price =get_post_meta($variation_id, '_regular_price', true).'<br>';
                 //echo $variation['image_src'];

             }
```

Comment: Can you provide some explanation for your code?  You can edit your answer to add this information.

Answer (score 0):

After searching for a long time I came up with this solution. It may not be the best way but it works and its simple. You can do a quick buy on product variations with Javascript...

First I added a secondary button next to my add to cart button 
Instant Buy

I used the hidden input that is standard for all Woocommerce. `<input type="hidden" name="variation_id" id="variation_num" class="variation_id" value="15959">`

I added the id (id="variation_num") to the input which is located in /wp-content/themes/YOUR THEME/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/variation-add-to-cart.php

Then at the bottom of this same variation-add-to-cart.php file I added my javascript. First get the value of the hidden input with the id we just added (var sel = document.getElementById('variation_num');)

If you have a option selected by default you need to select hidden input value on page load and update your link url by id (quick-buy)

```
sel.onload = function()
  { document.getElementById("quick-buy").href = "/checkout/?add-to-cart=" + this.value;}
```

Next you need a function to update url when option is selected or changed...

```
sel.onchange = function () { document.getElementById("quick-buy").href = "/checkout/?add-to-cart=" + this.value;}
```

So in total you will have the following..

```
<a href="/checkout/" id="quick-buy" class="instant-buy">Instant Buy</a>

<script>
var sel = document.getElementById('variation_num');

sel.onload = function()
  { document.getElementById("quick-buy").href = "/checkout/?add-to-cart=" + this.value;}

sel.onchange = function () { document.getElementById("quick-buy").href = "/checkout/?add-to-cart=" + this.value;}
</script>
```

Wala! I hope this saves others the time I wasted looking for a more complicated solution.

Also for simple products you will want to edit..
/wp-content/themes/YOUR THEME/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/simple.php

Add your new link / button, I used the same as on the variation products. As for the url I used php.

```
global $wpdb; //connect to WP database (may not be necessary)
global $product; //get product data (may not be necessary)
$pID = $product->id; //get current product id
```

Your button:

```
<a href="/checkout/?add-to-cart=<?php echo $pID?>" class="instant-buy">Instant Buy</a>
```